# Python: pulling a reference from a list of objects with the for loop

Tags: object, python-3.x, reference

So I am pretty new to python so be kind.
I am trying to create a global sort of object directory as a base for all my programs as a means to keep track of all created object instances in my programs.

so..

I create a class that holds a list of object references ( not id's ).
example:

```
class objDirectory:
    name = ""
    count = 0
    objDir = []
    def __init__( self ):
        print( "Initiating object directory." )
        name = "objDirectory"
        self.count= 1
        self.objDir = [ self ]
        return
    def getObj( self, name ):
        print( "Searching directory for:", name )
        for o in self.objDir:
            if o.name is name:
                print( "Returning:", name )
                return obj
            else:
                print( "Search failed" )
            return
```

But, once an object is added to a list and I run the get script it does not return my object. I even verify by using directory.objDir[x]. ( this always references my object) .

What am I not doing, or doing wrong?

Thanks.

Results:

> > > setDirectory()
> > >       Initiating object directory.
> > >       Global directory reference set
> > >       test = obj( "test" )
> > >       Initiating: test
> > >       Duplicate check
> > >       Logging: test1
> > >       Object count: 2
> > >       t1 = directory.getObj( "test1" )
> > >       Searching directory for: test1
> > >       Search failed
> > >       print( directory.objDir )
> > >       [<**main**.objDirectory object at 0x032C86F0>, <**main**.obj object at 0x032C8710>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand how you plan to use this object, however I find that there are a few problems with the `__init__` method.
First of all, I guess that your object should be a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), however it is not. You define the class attributes here:

```
class objDirectory:
    name = ""
    count = 0
    objDir = []
```

But in your `__init__` method you always override them, instead of adding to them. This means that every time you will write something like `a=objDirectory()`, `count` will be set to 1 **for that instance**. Also, notice that (at least in python2.7), you'll need a `@classmethod` decorator for every function you wish be able to modify class attributes (as opposed to the instance's attributes). Like so:

```
class objDirectory:
    count=0

    @classmethod
    def add_object(cls):
        cls.count+=1
    def __init__(self):
        self.add_object()
```

This goes for `objDir` as well.
Second, in your `__init__` method, you have a variable called `name`, which is never used. Perhaps you meant `self.name`?

There are better ways to implement singletons, however here is a simple example that might be easier to understand if you're new to python:

```
class mySingleton(object):
    singletonObject = None
    def __new__(cls):
        if not cls.singletonObject:
            cls.singletonObject = super(mySingleton, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.singletonObject
```

The `__new__` method is a static method which creates the actual instance. The return value is the new instance created. Overriding it like so will let me get the same instance for each call to `mySingleton()`; the statement `mySingleton() is mySingleton()` will always be true.

Comment: Thank you so much I need to wrap my head around some of the things you have here but, I still have alot to learn.